# Issue with getops parameter

Tags: bash

Currently, I'm working on a bash script that is meant to have parameters passed through it.

My getOps lines:

```
while getopts ":s:d:e:*" opt; do
  case $opt in
    s) 
      kb_status
      ;;
    d)
      kb_disable
      ;;
    e)
      kb_enable
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The main issue is whenever I try to pass the script through

```
./myscript.sh -e`
```

I get the following message from my wildcard parameter:

> Invalid option: -e

However, when I run it as

```
./myscript.sh -ee
```

or have any second letter in the parameter, it passes perfectly fine. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the ":" character after the e in

```
while getopts ":s:d:e:*" opt; do
```

The ":" tells getopts to expect an argument after the -e option.

So if you want your script to just support -s -d and -e options, then do the following:

```
while getopts sde opt; do
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting `:` after `e` in the option list means that the `-e` option requires an argument. `-e` by itself is missing the argument, `-ee` sets the value of the argument to `e`.

Since you don't do anything with `$OPTARG`, it looks like you don't really require arguments to your options, so you shouldn't be using `:` after each of them.

```
while getopts ":sde*" opt; do
```

It's also unclear why you have `*` at the end of the option list. That will allow `"-*"`, but the `case` block will report that as an error.